# How to add new content types to XPM

Tags: experience-manager, cme

I'm trying to add a few new content types to my publication but they won't show up in the sidebar when I click "Create and insert new content" in XPM.

I have followed the procedures as described here:

http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-28059E6B-6630-42B3-A1DE-70043CD4F5BC

Which means:
 - I have created a prototype component
 - I have added it to the Publication's Content Types
 - I have enabled it for inline editing in the settings menu (on both the parent and the child publication, to be sure).

I'm using the MTSUser to rule out any privilege issues.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Did you map your new Content Types to your Page Template in the Inline Editing section of the Settings menu?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you published your **Prototype Component** to your Staging website?